# Kernel compiling - Error during sync of the configuration

Tags: kernel, linux-kernel, compiling

I am trying to compile the `4.19` kernel on my Linux Mint machine. I copied my current config (which is from `4.15`), opened `make menuconfig` in order to append a local version string, saved it and then tried `make`. However I get this error:

```
scripts/kconfig/conf  --syncconfig Kconfig

*** Error during sync of the configuration.

scripts/kconfig/Makefile:69: recipe for target 'syncconfig' failed
make[2]: *** [syncconfig] Error 1
Makefile:539: recipe for target 'syncconfig' failed
make[1]: *** [syncconfig] Error 2
Makefile:635: recipe for target 'include/config/auto.conf' failed
make: *** [include/config/auto.conf] Error 2
```

I also tried not using `make menuconfig` but when I type `make` I get a bunch of questions about some options I don't have a clue what they are for (I guess those are the same as with `make config`).
Another thing I tried was using `make defconfig` which stated `Default configuration is based on 'x86_64_defconfig'`. However when executing `make` afterwards I get the exact same error.

I have the feeling that there are some sort of errors being introduced in the config or that I am missing something that is needed for compiling the kernel source. However I have no idea where I can get more information about those `Error 1` and `Error 2`.
Does somebody has an idea what could be wrong? If needed I'll upload my `.config`-file so that you can have a look at it.

EDIT:
I also tried it with the `4.18` kernel version but this time I didn't even touch the config that comes with it from git. Still I get the very same error. I suspect that there is something wrong on my machine (some missing dependencies or something like that). However - as stated above - I do not know where I should start searching as the error message that unspecific...

EDIT2:
I have installed a new distribution (from Linux Mint to KDE Neon) but I am still getting the very same error. I start suspecting that this might actually be a bug in the kernel somehow...

Comment: I added an answer to this question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61169878/1487069

Comment: Thank you for the hint! :)

Comment: @CarloWood, if you already posted an answer to this question there, please consider posting it here as an answer too to complete this Q&A.

Comment: @Raven, if you learned a solution to your problem, please [consider posting it as an answer to your question below](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer).

Comment: @RomanRiabenko I would if I had an answer. I ended up not compiling kernels myself anymore and thus did not keep poking around for possible solutions